# How to set up a distance between two nodes using SKConstraint?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 4 nodes of enemies. They are appearing on a scene from the right to the left bound. But often they are appearing in groups for some reason. It looks unpleasantly so I want to set the distance between them. I know that I can do it with SKConstraint, but XCode says that I'm doing something wrong. That's how I tried to do it:

```
mouse = SKSpriteNode(texture: mouseArray[0]);
self.mouse.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + self.mouse.size.width, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 138)
self.mouse.size = CGSizeMake(self.mouse.size.width + self.mouse.size.width / 2, self.mouse.size.height + mouse.size.height / 2)
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range: 50...100, toNode: cat)
```

Xcode tells me that argument for parameter ToPoint is missing. I don't know why and what point it is talking about. 
I couldn't find examples of using SKConstraint.distance online. How to use constraints properly for this purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKConstraint`'s `distance` class method takes an [SKRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKRange_Ref/index.html) as its first argument not a closed range (e.g., 10...50). For an example,

**Swift 2**

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit:50, upperLimit:100)
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, toNode:cat)
mouse.constraints = [constraint]
```

**Swift 3**

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit:50, upperLimit:100)
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: cat)
mouse.constraints = [constraint]
```

Comment: I pasted your code, but in `let constraint = SKConstraint(range, toNode:cat)` Xcode gives me an error `Extra argument in call` :(

Comment: That works, thanks! But my mouse though is now positioned lower than average. Can I specify that it should be horizontal range?

Comment: If your `mouse` sprite has a physics body, you can add a floor (with an edge loop or chain) to your scene to limit the mouse's `y` position.